# Eureka First Bootstrap - not working unless eureka server has config server URI

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to get Eureka set up to use cloud config server, but the Eureka server is not able to find an instance of configserver at startup:

```
WARN 17584 --- [           main] lientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration : No instances found of configserver (CONFIGSERVER)
```

Not sure what I'm missing in terms of configuration. Config server is as follows:

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: dev

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://XXXXXXX/config.git
          username: XXXXXXX
          password: XXXXXXX

server:
  port: 9999

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9998/eureka/
```

Began with discovery service configured as bootstrap.yml (1). Seems that when configserver registers, discovery service should then be able to retrieve its config and start up properly, but instead discovery service is unable to startup completely and config server is never able to register. When I added additional config in bootstrap.yml (2), both services start, but discovery service never uses the config server to retrieve its config (discoveryservice.yml). If I provide the spring.cloud.config.uri property, discovery service starts up and retrieves its config from the server as expected. Makes me think I'm missing something, or is Eureka not able to retrieve its configuration from the config server without the config server uri?

bootstrap.yml (1)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discoveryservice

---

spring:
  profiles: dev

  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
```

bootstrap.yml (2)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discoveryservice

---

spring:
  profiles: dev

  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true

server:
  port: 9998

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

discoveryservice.yml (from config server git repo):

```
server:
  port: 9998

---

spring:
  profiles: dev

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Comment: A few questions/comments. What version are you using? Also `eureka.instance.hostname` is the name to register the current service as. It is likely only the same when run on a workstation.

Comment: 1.1.0.RC1 for spring-cloud-config-server and spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server, 1.3.3.RELEASE for spring-boot. This will ultimately be run in AWS so the hostname in those profiles has been set to the ec2 hostname, i just left those profiles out for simplicity, but i see the same issue locally as i do in AWS. Thought the registration name came from spring.application.name? Once both apps have started, config is able to register as DiscoveryClient_CONFIGSERVER, but discovery service just registers it without then retrieving its own config

Comment: My thinking was that config service would start and attempt to register itself and will retry until discovery service starts, at which point it registers and discovery service then initializes itself with its configuration from the config server... perhaps I'm misunderstanding the startup sequence. Trying to understand if and how discovery service can use config service for its configuration

Comment: configserver won't reinitialize itself. It can initialize itself from git on it's own, but it shouldn't have `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: true`. That's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Right, configserver can't, but discovery service should be able to obtain its config from configserver once it (configserver) registers itself right? Otherwise it seems that discovery service needs the configserver uri which defeats the purpose of the eureka first setup. Or should I just assume that discovery service must have all of its own configuration and not depend on configserver for that? Essentially, I guess the question is: is `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: true` a valid option for discovery service?

Comment: Not really on it's own. You'd have to trigger a refresh.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.